# Azure Node SDK - 500 response with filter option

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sdk

I am seeing a weird error on the with Azure Node SDK where I get a 500 error back anytime i include anything in the filter attribute of the options parameter. I am using the Usage Details call within the ConsumptionManagementClient class. Code is below:

```
const credentials = await MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(config.appId, config.apiKey, config.tenantId);
let client = new ConsumptionManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);
const scope = `/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}`;
const options = { filter: "usageStart ge datetime'2017-10-13T00:00:00.000Z'"};
let usage = await client.usageDetails.list(scope, options);
```

The above code produces a 500 error(even tried searching for other things another example being "billableQuantity ge 0.001") but it seems to error out no matter what i give it.

The code works fine when i try using another one of the options paramters:

```
const credentials = await MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(config.appId, config.apiKey, config.tenantId);
let client = new ConsumptionManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);
const scope = `/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}`;
const options = { top: 50 };
let usage = await client.usageDetails.list(scope, options);
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Reading the documentation here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/3431d0d1a82f920c4a4e826d63b20f32d0815418/lib/services/consumptionManagement/lib/operations/usageDetails.js, it seems you can only `filter` by `usageEnd`. Could that be the reason for this 500 error you're getting?

Comment: i totally missed that the first time around :( it looks like i am still getting the error when i try "usageEnd ge datetime'2017-10-13T00:00:00.000Z'" any other ideas?

Comment: Just a hunch: Can you drop `datetime` from your filter criteria? Something like: `const options = { filter: "usageEnd ge '2017-10-13T00:00:00.000Z'"};`

Comment: no luck, still getting a 500

Comment: Have you tried `const options = { filter: "usageEnd ge 2017-10-13T00:00:00Z" };`?